# Getting german timezone display string

Tags: java, timezone

I need to programatically determine the timezone display string (ie. PST/ PDT for California) for sites around the world. My problem is with Germany;
no matter how i turn it, I can't get it to show the display name in German (MESZ).

Here are a few tings I've tried:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("MET");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
Date date = new Date();
date.setTime(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
String displayName = tz.getDisplayName(tz.inDaylightTime(date), TimeZone.SHORT, Locale.GERMANY);
```

For this i get displayName as MEST (the english version of my needed MESZ).

If instead of "MET" i use "Europe/Berlin", I get CEST, even worse...
I've also tried playing with the locale param in the getDisplayName method, not passing it, passing GERMANY, and passing GERMAN, but the results dont change.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks,
Yotam.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on Sun's jre library files and found that for the locale you mentioned the library knows only "MET" for "Zentraleuropäische Zeit" and "MEST" for "Zentraleuropäische Sommerzeit". No other names are listed in the code. So, either it is a bug(typo) or it is done for some unclear reason.